# I’m trying enter multiple data in a file row wise and have to append it again and again. but its not working

Tags: python, file, file-handling

pass data in a function which is storing record in a text file.

```
def addData(val,val2):

    outfil=open('taxt.txt','a+')
    outfil.write(str(val).strip()+str(val2).strip())
    outfil.close
```

Comment: (1) Repair the indentation in your question's code. (2) To call (execute) a function append parentheses.

Comment: for posting I did code like that therwise at my IDE I’m doing it with proper indentation. i didn’t get your second point

Comment: `but its not working` - what's wrong?

Comment: I think @MichaelButscher is referring to the last line which should be: `outfil.close()`

Answer (score 0):

file was not closed properly should be close()

```
def addData(val,val2):
outfil=open('taxt.txt','a+')
outfil.write(str(valu).strip()+str(val2).strip() )
outfil.close()
```

Comment: Remember to indent the code within a function! It's **extremely** important in Python to have the correct indentation as it affects the behaviour of your code.